# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError using jni

Tags: java, java-native-interface

```
class HelloWorld {
    public native void print();  //native method
    static   //static initializer code
    {
        try{
            String path = System.getProperty("java.library.path");
            System.out.println(path);
        System.loadLibrary("CLibHelloWorld1");
        //System.load("C:/TE_CDA_Project/Test/native/CLibHelloWorld1.dll");
        //Runtime.getRuntime().load("C:/TE_CDA_Project/Test/native/CLibHelloWorld1.dll");

    System.out.println("Loaded CallApi");
    }catch(UnsatisfiedLinkError e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    HelloWorld hw = new HelloWorld();

    hw.print();


}
```

}

Output:

```
C:\TE_CDA_Project\Test\native
Loaded CallApi
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Graph.HelloWorld.print()V
    at Graph.HelloWorld.print(Native Method)
    at Graph.HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:26)
```

Comment: This is most probably because the Path variable for java.library.path isn't currently set. This is the path from where Java extracts required libraries.

Comment: @Paritosh: I think you should post your native code also. This exception normally occurs due to wrong signature of the native method. See the example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16518490/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-jni/16519301#16519301 (if you are facing the same problem, dont forget to +1 that answer)

Answer (score 1):

add this to your C Compiler additional options it worked for me:

```
   -Wl,--export-all-symbols -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Graph.HelloWorld.print()V
```

I can assume you specified the path to native library correctly, this problem probably means Java cannot map the native method to actual native function. So there should be some problem with the native method in the library, probably the method signature which you are trying to access may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

That the error is saying is that you have attempted to call a method like this:

```
void native print();
```

declared in `Graph.HelloWorld`, but the JVM has not been able to find the native code implementation for that method.

This could be caused by a couple of things:

- You application has not made the `System.loadLibrary(...)` to load the native library.
- The native library that you loaded doesn't declare a method that matches the name and signature of the method on the `Graph.HelloWorld` class.  (The classname could be wrong, or the method name, or the argument types or result types.)

---

While I have your attention, `Graph.HelloWorld` is a serious Java style violation.  Assuming that `Graph` is a package name, it should be entirely lower case.  Furthermore, it is advisable (for anything other than "throw away" code) to follow the convention of prefixing the package name with reversed domain name ... so that your "graph" package doesn't accidentally collide with someone else's.