# Problem connecting Java and Prolog with JPL

Tags: java, prolog, jpl

I wanted to connect Java and Swi Prolog together using JPL.
When I added the library to my project on Intellij the code compiled and when I tried to run a query I got a runtime error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jpl in java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12\bin, C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin, C:\WINDOWS\system32, C:\WINDOWS, c:\swipl\bin, ${env_var:PATH}, .]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2660)
at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:827)
at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1902)
at org.jpl7.JPL.loadNativeLibrary(JPL.java:114)
at org.jpl7.fli.Prolog.<clinit>(Prolog.java:71)
at org.jpl7.Query.open(Query.java:369)
at org.jpl7.Term.textToTerm(Term.java:155)
at org.jpl7.Query.<init>(Query.java:169)
at Main.main(Main.java:7)
```

I have the swi prolog 64 bit.

I've tried uninstalling it and use the 32 bit but it did not work.

What I did so far:

I added SWI_HOME_DIR to my Environment Variables.
I also added the swi path to Path variable.
I added the jpl library to my project (and it added it successfully).

The code I was trying to run:

```
import org.jpl7.*;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Query q = new Query("true");
        q.hasSolution();

        Map<String,Term>[] res = q.allSolutions();

        for (int i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(res[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: According to the [**documentation**](https://jpl7.org/Deployment): *"In Windows, `jpl.dll` can go in any folder on your `PATH`; perhaps `%SWI_HOME_DIR%\bin` or your Windows’ system folder."* --- Is the **`jpl.dll`** file there, in a folder listed on your PATH? Is it the 64-bit version? I'm not asking if the `bin` folder is on your path, I'm asking if that specific file can be found on the path.

Comment: Yes, and it is the 64 bit version.

Comment: So if you do a `dir c:\swipl\bin\jpl.dll` from a command prompt, it will list the file? And you are running 64-bit Java? And you are *sure* the file is the 64-bit version? If yes to all, then the file might be corrupt, to try getting another copy.

Comment: I have jpl.jar not .dll

Comment: Then the error message is exactly right, huh? Go figure. Next time, read the comment, because my first comment explicitly said **`jpl.dll`**. I even **bolded** it so you could see, but I guess you didn't.

Answer (score 1):

So, is `jpl.dll` in any of the listed directories:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12\bin   ... probably not 
C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin            ... probably not
C:\WINDOWS\system32                ... probably not
C:\WINDOWS                         ... probably not
c:\swipl\bin                       ... apparently yes as c:\swipl\bin\jpl.dll exists?
${env_var:PATH}                    ... apparently not
```

Try the suggestion from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16518490/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-jni) in your Java program:

```
File nativeFile = new File(filename + ".dll");
    if (!nativeFile.exists())
        System.exit(1);

System.load(nativeFile);
```

Note that just having `jpl.jar` is not enough. One needs the `jpl.dll` file, too. `jpl.jar` is good for the Java part of the Java-Prolog bridge, but to be able to call a non-JVM compilate, we need to get into system-level details, Hence the dll file.

See troubleshooting tips here: [JPL Deploying for users - on Windows](https://jpl7.org/DeploymentWindows)

From the above page:

> If the Java examples complain that
>
> `The dynamic link library libpl.dll could not be found in the specified path`
>
> or
>
> `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\paul\bin\jpl.dll: Can't find dependent libraries`
>
> then there is no SWI-Prolog library `libpl.dll` in any folder on your
> `PATH`: you should have a `PATH` entry such as `C:\Program Files\pl\bin`.

The `libpl.dll` should contain the code for SWI-Prolog itself.

Comment: I have jpl.jar not .dll

Comment: @Danny That's not enough. The JAR file is good for the Java part of the brige, but we need to get closer to the system to load the Prolog Processor and call it. Hence the dll file.

Comment: OK I FOUND IT, I put it in the folder, now I have a different exception:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\swipl\bin\jpl.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
 at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load0(Native Method)
 at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Class...

Comment: @Danny See extended answer.

Comment: I don't know man I can't get it to work. :(
Thank you for you kind help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221347/discussion-between-david-tonhofer-and-danny).

Comment: @Danny "dependent libraries" means other `.dll` files that the `jpl.dll` depends on. Were there others where you found the `jpl.dll` file? Copy them all, or better yet, add the folder that has them to the PATH in effect when running the program.